# Open My Documents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a link to a file in 'my documents' this is an internal web site. How can I open the users local MY Documents folder using JS or JQ

I used this code and thought the documents would appear in a web page but it didnt

```
address = "G:\systems Projects"  ; 

window.open(address,"Detail ","width=800,height=600"  )
```

Any help appreciated  ! , thanks

Answer (score 0):

use [`file://`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) protocol:

```
address = "file:///G:/systems Projects";
```